# Where can I find an svg or png of the Apple compose email icon?

Tags: ios, email, icon

I'm looking for an svg or png of the Apple `compose email` icon (on the far right in this picture). I haven't been able to find anything online. Does anyone know where I can source this?

[image]

Comment: Why? They are presumably copyright of Apple, so if you want access you'd have to ask them, though they may be available in certain developer frameworks if you're making an iOS/Mac app.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [SF symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/):

> square.and.pencil

[image]